# Can not create new projectin Android

Tags: android

Hi iam new in Android and I am facing a problem in creating new project. After clicking finish button I am getting error as follow.

Failed to load properties file for project 'VDemo'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this in groups.google.com.See [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-x86/browse_thread/thread/eedd8b3b7ca53e0d?fwc=1)

Here you have to set the environmental path's system variables. Which will
you get by *right clicking on My Computer properties Advanced Environmental
variables. *
**           Then you select *path* option from *System Variables** *and
select Edit option. Then u have to mentioned the *jdk's path as follows.
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_14\bin *after that give semi colon and set
the *avd* file path.

*
*
*C:\Documents and Settings\tpbhade.android\avd *like this*.** *Give the
semicolon. and click on ok button. Then u restart u r Eclipse. and go to
project menu unchecked Build Automatically option, and click on Build all
option. your problem will be solved.